# Redirecion a con barra (/) para todas las url de la web htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero me esta dando error cuando lo pongo en mi htaccess

```
# si no existe un archivo que coincida con la solicitud...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y si no termina con una barra, redireccionar a la misma dirección pero con la barra
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]
```

también he probado con este y no me funciona

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://MIURL.es/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

¿Alguna idea? Es un wordpress.

Comment: como es la estructura de permalinks? ( si termina en `/` el wordpress le agrega en todas las url )  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1852

Comment: En permalinks tengo esta ---> Nombre de la entrada: http://miweb.es/pagina-ejemplo/   <-- pero y por defecto me las carga así , pero si yo le quito la barra me carga la web sin la barra y quiero que redireccione a con ella, ya que sino me indexa duplicadamente en google

Comment: si el permalink es `/%postname%/` ( termina en `/` ) le va a agregar la `/` a todas las url

Comment: Si, lo hace al generar losenlaces de la web, todos van con barra, pero si tu le quitas la barra del navegador y accedes no te redireciona a con barra, te carga la misma web sin la barra.

Comment: en los sitios que tengo con wordpress: ie11, chrome, edge, y firefox redireccionan a la url con `/` . si te preocupa el SEO podes poner un plugin onda  Yoast SEO que te revisa la configuración y se encarga de enviar los sitemaps con las url canónicas

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este nuevo .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Lo pones en la raiz si utilizas algun framework.

Comment: Este siempre redirecciona hacia el index, me ha funcionado en todos los proyectos.

Comment: Como hacia el index? mi intencion es que todas las páginas de la web acaben con /, no solo el index, sino que /blog/  ,   /categorias/   etc...

Comment: Como puedes ver, indica que siempre mientras no le des la estructura de controlador/funcion/parametro el buscara el index por defecto, obviamente si le das la estructura el redireccionara de la forma que deba, ps de esa manera lo entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede servir.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Si el archivo o carpeta no existe, y no tiene barra al final, le pone una. Tendrías que agregar algunas condicionantes para redirigir el contenido de un archivo como **no_existe.html**, ya que te redirecciona a **no_existe.htm/**.

Las importantes son las ultimas dos lineas.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```